# Select Item in String List In SQL Based On Value in Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL table with a column (Grouped_Identifer) that has a string list.  The items on the list are separated by commas.   There is another column (Position) which has a value.  I would like to create or return a column let's call it Position_Identifer that has the portion or item in the Grouped_Identifer which correspond to the value in the Position column.

So we start with the following table:

[image]

And would like to end up with a table that looks like the following:

[image]

The string list in the Grouped_Identifier column can vary in the number (up to 20) of items.

Comment: which database -Eg: sql-server, oracle, postgresql are you using

Comment: So I am using MS sql

Comment: You should fix your data model.  Storing multiple values in a string column is an anti-pattern.

Comment: I totally agree.  Unfortunately, this is the crap I am given.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not provide the position in `string_split()`.  And, there is no guarantee on the ordering of results from the function.

If the string has no duplicates, you can use `charindex()` to find the position:

```
select t.*, s.value
from t outer apply
     (select *
      from (select s.value,
                   row_number() over (order by charindex(',' + s.value + ',', ',' + t.gi + ',')) as seqnum
            from string_split(t.gi, ',') s
           ) s
      where seqnum = t.pos
     ) s;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9742d36bc2c70aedad732434f6507239) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I modified your script replacing with my column names and am getting error messages saying the column name is invalid. It is referring to s.value which is what I am hoping to solve for.  Trying to debug and see what is going.

Comment: @Neo28 . . . Have you seen the db<>fiddle?  The code actually works.

Comment: Yes. I was able to take your exact code and get the same results.   I am trying to modify and see if works straight from my source table.

Comment: @Neo28 . . . How about you set up your source table with sample data in db<>fiddle?

Comment: I finally got it to work!  Thanks for taking the time on this.

Answer (score 0):

The new column can be calculated with:

```
select substring(Grouped_Identifier,Position*15-14,14) as Position_Identifier from yourTable
```

Comment: That's a pretty good calculation that would work on the data presented,  however, I ran it through some additional records and the length for the items on the list are not all 14.  Some are shorter.   The items are separated out by commas.

Comment: You did not say that in your description! :-)

Comment: :-)  Your solution is elegant.  I will use it when I come across a similar scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using string_split if your sql version supports this as follows

```
with data
  as (select '008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63' as gi,'1' as pos union all
      select '008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63' as gi,'2' as pos union all
      select '008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63' as gi,'3' as pos 
     )
   ,cte_d
   as(
select *
       ,row_number() over(partition by pos order by pos) as rn
  from data d
cross apply string_split(d.gi,',') x
     )
select * 
  from cte_d
where rn=pos
```

In older versions you may use this

```
with data
  as (select '008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63' as gi,'1' as pos union all
      select '008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63' as gi,'2' as pos union all
      select '008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63' as gi,'3' as pos 
     )
    ,cte_d
    as(
SELECT a.gi
      ,a.pos
      ,split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS split_val  
      ,row_number() over(partition by pos order by pos) as rn
 FROM (SELECT pos
             ,CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(gi, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS col
             ,gi
         FROM data 
       ) a 
 CROSS APPLY col.nodes ('/M') AS split(a)
      )
select *
  from cte_d
 where rn=pos


+-------------------------------------------+-----+---------------+----+
|                    gi                     | pos |     value     | rn |
+-------------------------------------------+-----+---------------+----+
| 008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63 |   1 | 008300000;#61 |  1 |
| 008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63 |   2 | 008300000;#62 |  2 |
| 008300000;#61,008300000;#62,008300000;#63 |   3 | 008300000;#63 |  3 |
+-------------------------------------------+-----+---------------+----+
```

dbfiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f753ad7c97255351efc704ebdd966c3

Comment: As you got the tables with you, you would rename the"from data" to "from <your_table_name>"

Comment: I am trying to use your first chunk of code as I have a more recent version of MS SQL that supports string_split.   I tried replacing the hard coded strings with the column names but am getting invalid column names error msg.  Any thoughts on what might be the issue?

Comment: can you share the exact SQL you are trying

Comment: The most likely issue is that the column you are using is named as grouped_identifier and position. So you would need to replace my SQL with these values against gi and pos

Comment: Yes.  That is what I am doing since I have thousands of records that I need to go through.      with data as (select [Grouped_Identifier] as gi,[Position] as pos ) ,cte_d as( select * ,row_number() over(partition by pos order by pos) as rn from data d cross apply string_split(d.gi,',') x ) select * from cte_d where rn=pos

Comment: in the data block, you want to include the table you are selecting the cols grouped_identifier and position. Eg: with data 
  as (select [Grouped_Identifier] as gi
             ,[Position] as pos 
    from <your_table_name>   
   ) 
  ,cte_d 
    as( select * 
               ,row_number() over(partition by pos order by pos) as rn 
    from data d 
   cross apply string_split(d.gi,',') x 
    ) 
   select * from cte_d where rn=pos

Comment: seems like it is getting close...so after I include  "from <your_table_name>",  I get error msg stating Recursive common table expression...does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.